# Call to a member function add_rule() on a non-object

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I want the page mysite.com/product to be accessed with the URL

> mysite.com/product/productname instead of 
>   mysite.com/product?name=productname

I am trying to achieve this with the code in the plugins main file:

```
 add_rewrite_rule('^(product)/([^/]*)/?', 'product?name=$matches[1]','top');
```

but I am getting the error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function add_rule() on a non-object in
>   /location/wp-includes/rewrite.php on line 21

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling it too early. Call it on the init hook or later, e.g.:

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_alexes_rules' );
function add_alexes_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^(product)/([^/]*)/?', 'product?name=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Comment: Thanks you were right, doesn't appear to be doing anything though as if I do var_dump($_GET) when I visit mysite.com/product/productname it returns any empty array but that's a new problem

Comment: looks like I need to use http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag